# jquery .animate() and .done()

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I'm trying to fire up a function after the animation has finished but i can't make it work.

Here is my code:

```
var count = 3;
var timer = setInterval(function () {
    handleTimer(count);
}, 1000);

function endCountdown() {
    $('.begin-btn').html("GO!");
}

function handleTimer() {
    if (count === 0) {
        clearInterval(timer);
        endCountdown();
    } else {
        $('.begin-btn').html(count);
        count--;
    }
}


$('.begin-mrsuper').delay(500).animate({
    "left": "4px"
}, "slow").promise().done(function (handleTimer) {});
```

I tryed and:

```
    $('.begin-mrsuper').delay(500).animate({"left":"4px"}, "slow").promise().done(function(){ handleTimer(); });
```

But the 3,2,1, GO timer starts before the animation finishes, any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the `setInterval` part into a function, or it will be executed once you called it.

```
var count = 3, timer = null;
var foo = function() {
    timer = setInterval(function () {
        handleTimer(count);
    }, 1000);
};

function endCountdown() {
    $('.begin-btn').html("GO!");
}

function handleTimer() {
    if (count === 0) {
        clearInterval(timer);
        endCountdown();
    } else {
        $('.begin-btn').html(count);
        count--;
    }
}


$('.begin-mrsuper').delay(500).animate({
    "left": "4px"
}, "slow").promise().done(foo);
```

Comment: If I paste your code it doesn't work anymore, but I saw that I put .done(function (handleTimer) {});  instead of .done(handleTimer); and now it works, thanks.

Comment: @xdazz Good post! @Marinescu Edward. Good tests! Similar case with respect to jquery's `.done()` `resolve` "order" http://stackoverflow.com/a/22496969/2801559

Answer (score 1):

Something like this might just work:

```
$('.begin-mrsuper').delay(500).animate({
    "left": "4px"
}, "slow", function(){ handleTimer(); }).promise();
```